# Writing data in SharedPrefer - Application stops responding

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using the following code to store data in shared pref.
However when ever this code is called , the virtual device tells me that the application
stopped responding. Any suggestions why this is happening ?

```
SharedPreferences spref =       this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
editor.putString("td", "SharedPref"); //name-value pair
editor.commit();
```

Edit:
Now I am using the following

SharedPreferences spref = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
    editor.putString("td", "SharedPref");
    editor.commit();

But I am still Getting "The application has stopped unexpectedly..Please Try Again"

Looks like there was some problem with the virtual device. After recreating it my app started working fine.

Comment: Try using getSharedPreferences instead, and paste the logcat.

Comment: Are you trying to use this inside an Activity class or outside an Activity class? If it is inside Activity class `getSharedPreferences()` with two arguments is enough. First Argument is the name of the file that going to save in SharedPreference location and the second one is the _mode_. You have given only the _mode_.

Comment: @AnujAroshA I am still getting the error. Please check my edit code

Comment: Hey Adam, could you post more of your code? Sorry to say but the other people should be wrong when they say you need to use getSharedPreference, or use external storage. Using getPreferences() is legal, if not always what you WANT to be doing. However, the code as you have it now should be legal, and thus we need more information.  Specifically, could you post your entire Java file and the logcat output?

Comment: @aamit915 thanks but I finally solved the problem. Looks like there was some problem with the Virtual Device I recreated it and it works fine thanks again folks

Comment: Glad it worked. Was wondering what the problem could be :) as for what I was saying earlier, if you're using getPreferences(int mode), although it's legal, it's recommended if you want preferences that are unique to the Activity, not your entire application. So the difference between that and getSharedPreferences(string, int), you're creating a 'file' with that String name, that you can access throughout your application by subsequent calls to getSharedPreferences with the same string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my apps i prefer using my own location names. Declare

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
```

then in the code

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);  //0 might be bad naming, can just use MODE_PRIVATE or something instead depending on what you need to do :)
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putInt("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

shouldn't be any problems with this if the info you're saving is correct

**EDIT**

you also need to update your manifest with the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: outside, i usually have it at the top right after the minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the wrong initialization

```
final SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

This will work.